# Heroku ActionView::Template::Error (Path '/original_1/image.png' not found):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, paperclip

I'm trying to deploy to Heroku using the `paperclip-dropbox gem` and I'm getting the following message when the page is rendered: **We're sorry, but something went wrong. If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.** And I've `heroku run rake db:migrate`'d to no avail. Here are my logs ...

```
2014-08-19T14:26:15.146028+00:00 heroku[run.6755]: Process exited with status 0
2014-08-19T14:26:19.672145+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ListingsController#index as HTML
2014-08-19T14:26:19.669725+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 108.30.115.85 at 2014-08-19 14:26:19 +0000
2014-08-19T14:26:20.068003+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=jeolry.herokuapp.com request_id=3bad32bb-fa60-42bf-81dd-c88ee2c6df24 fwd="108.30.115.85" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=404ms status=500 bytes=899
2014-08-19T14:26:20.066870+00:00 app[web.1]:     5: 
2014-08-19T14:26:20.066866+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (Path '/original_3/butterfly-bracelet.png' not found):
2014-08-19T14:26:20.066873+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:       <%= image_tag listing.image.url %><br>
2014-08-19T14:26:20.064990+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 393ms
2014-08-19T14:26:20.066896+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:         <h3><%= listing.name %><br></h3>
2014-08-19T14:26:20.066863+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-08-19T14:26:20.066871+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:     <div class="thumbnail">
2014-08-19T14:26:20.064816+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered listings/index.html.erb within layouts/application (390.7ms)
2014-08-19T14:26:20.066894+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:       <div class="caption">
2014-08-19T14:26:20.066868+00:00 app[web.1]:     4:   <div class="col-md-3">
2014-08-19T14:26:20.066898+00:00 app[web.1]:    10:         <p><%= number_to_currency(listing.price) %></p><br>
2014-08-19T14:26:20.066899+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/listings/index.html.erb:7:in `block in _app_views_listings_index_html_erb___253872055815423356_70175409465320'
2014-08-19T14:26:20.066902+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-08-19T14:26:20.066901+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/listings/index.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_listings_index_html_erb___253872055815423356_70175409465320'
2014-08-19T14:26:20.066904+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-08-19T14:42:28+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-08-19T14:43:01+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2014-08-19T14:43:02.260069+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2014-08-19T14:43:01.712521+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v12 created by antis.michael@gmail.com
2014-08-19T14:43:01.712447+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy b7931a0 by antis.michael@gmail.com
2014-08-19T14:43:06.055384+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-08-19 14:43:06] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2014-08-19T14:43:06.055405+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
2014-08-19T14:43:06.055397+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
2014-08-19T14:43:06.055400+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
2014-08-19T14:43:06.055391+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
2014-08-19T14:43:06.055393+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
2014-08-19T14:43:06.055403+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
2014-08-19T14:43:06.055398+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:14:in `run'
2014-08-19T14:43:06.055395+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2014-08-19T14:43:06.055406+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
2014-08-19T14:43:06.055408+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
2014-08-19T14:43:06.055410+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2014-08-19T14:43:06.055412+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:8:in `require'
2014-08-19T14:43:06.055413+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2014-08-19T14:43:06.055415+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-08-19 14:43:06] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2014-08-19T14:43:06.055416+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-08-19 14:43:06] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2014-08-19T14:43:06.055418+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2014-08-19T14:43:06.055401+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
2014-08-19T14:43:05.405186+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2014-08-19T14:43:07.520950+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2014-08-19T14:43:05.979467+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 3620 -e production`
2014-08-19T14:43:14.789590+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-08-19 14:43:14] INFO  ruby 2.1.2 (2014-05-08) [x86_64-linux]
2014-08-19T14:43:14.789079+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-08-19 14:43:14] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2014-08-19T14:43:14.790696+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-08-19 14:43:14] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=3620
2014-08-19T14:43:15.082871+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2014-08-19T14:43:22.870045+00:00 app[web.1]: => Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
2014-08-19T14:43:22.870041+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.1.4 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:3620
2014-08-19T14:43:22.870043+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2014-08-19T14:43:22.870046+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2014-08-19T14:43:22.870035+00:00 app
[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2014-08-19T14:43:22.870048+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 54.237.200.138 at 2014-08-19 14:43:22 +0000
2014-08-19T14:43:23.014934+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ListingsController#index as */*
2014-08-19T14:43:23.520908+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=jeolry.herokuapp.com request_id=3e8dbea7-c779-443f-a36d-18742c3157da fwd="54.237.200.138" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=667ms status=500 bytes=394
2014-08-19T14:43:23.513288+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered listings/index.html.erb within layouts/application (454.2ms)
2014-08-19T14:43:23.513478+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 498ms
2014-08-19T14:43:23.515563+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-08-19T14:43:23.515567+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (Path '/original_3/butterfly-bracelet.png' not found):
2014-08-19T14:43:23.515569+00:00 app[web.1]:     4:   <div class="col-md-3">
2014-08-19T14:43:23.515570+00:00 app[web.1]:     5: 
2014-08-19T14:43:23.515572+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:     <div class="thumbnail">
2014-08-19T14:43:23.515574+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:       <%= image_tag listing.image.url %><br>
2014-08-19T14:43:23.515575+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:       <div class="caption">
2014-08-19T14:43:23.515577+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:         <h3><%= listing.name %><br></h3>
2014-08-19T14:43:23.515582+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/listings/index.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_listings_index_html_erb__1966724572050443963_70111889363500'
2014-08-19T14:43:23.515579+00:00 app[web.1]:    10:         <p><%= number_to_currency(listing.price) %></p><br>
2014-08-19T14:43:23.515580+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/listings/index.html.erb:7:in `block in _app_views_listings_index_html_erb__1966724572050443963_70111889363500'
2014-08-19T14:43:23.515583+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-08-19T14:43:23.515585+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-08-19T14:43:24.944691+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by antis.michael@gmail.com
2014-08-19T14:43:29.092006+00:00 heroku[run.9380]: State changed from starting to up
2014-08-19T14:43:33.526407+00:00 heroku[run.9380]: Process exited with status 0
2014-08-19T14:43:28.908491+00:00 heroku[run.9380]: Awaiting client
2014-08-19T14:43:28.968940+00:00 heroku[run.9380]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2014-08-19T14:43:33.540042+00:00 heroku[run.9380]: State changed from up to complete
2014-08-19T14:57:43.111935+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ListingsController#index as HTML
2014-08-19T14:57:43.109509+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 108.30.115.85 at 2014-08-19 14:57:43 +0000
2014-08-19T14:57:43.506607+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=jeolry.herokuapp.com request_id=b619f29c-371d-43da-8f99-08021baf50b3 fwd="108.30.115.85" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=397ms status=500 bytes=925
2014-08-19T14:57:43.709321+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=jeolry.herokuapp.com request_id=f292a30f-0505-4402-b8be-880867636be6 fwd="108.30.115.85" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=889
2014-08-19T14:57:43.497729+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered listings/index.html.erb within layouts/application (383.8ms)
2014-08-19T14:57:43.501205+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-08-19T14:57:43.501210+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (Path '/original_3/butterfly-bracelet.png' not found):
2014-08-19T14:57:43.501211+00:00 app[web.1]:     4:   <div class="col-md-3">
2014-08-19T14:57:43.501213+00:00 app[web.1]:     5: 
2014-08-19T14:57:43.501216+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:       <%= image_tag listing.image.url %><br>
2014-08-19T14:57:43.501223+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/listings/index.html.erb:7:in `block in _app_views_listings_index_html_erb__1966724572050443963_70111888095400'
2014-08-19T14:57:43.501215+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:     <div class="thumbnail">
2014-08-19T14:57:43.501226+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-08-19T14:57:43.501221+00:00 app[web.1]:    10:         <p><%= number_to_currency(listing.price) %></p><br>
2014-08-19T14:57:43.501218+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:       <div class="caption">
2014-08-19T14:57:43.501219+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:         <h3><%= listing.name %><br></h3>
2014-08-19T14:57:43.501224+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/listings/index.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_listings_index_html_erb__1966724572050443963_70111888095400'
2014-08-19T14:57:43.501227+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-08-19T14:57:43.498108+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 386ms
2014-08-19T15:01:36.485827+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bin/rails console` by antis.michael@gmail.com
2014-08-19T15:01:40.141866+00:00 heroku[run.8979]: Awaiting client
2014-08-19T15:01:40.347224+00:00 heroku[run.8979]: Starting process with command `bin/rails console`
2014-08-19T15:01:40.527050+00:00 heroku[run.8979]: State changed from starting to up
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Because there was only one item in my DB, I deleted the record and it now works.